# iOS sample projects to learn from

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am just starting iOS development. I read some tutorials, watched stuff on iTunes U and wrote some sample code myself. Now I want to take the next step. I want to learn about best practices for iOS development in XCode.

*Are there any well written and well organized iOS projects that one could take a look at?*

(As I see it, iOS is not exactly the place for open source enthusiasts, however.)

Thanks
Mike.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any Open-source iPhone applications around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around)

Comment: As you can see from that question, there are actually quite a few open source iOS applications out there.  Additional sample projects can be found in the resources listed in the question [How-to articles for iPhone development and Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c).

Comment: Thank you very much for the SO links. I looked for older questions but had wrong search terms in mind.

Comment: The other question mentioned above has been removed

Comment: There are lot of Applications around. If your a startup guy apple documentation and [sample code](http://way2ios.com) is more than enough.

Comment: Check this.. http://iosdevelopertutorial.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree with several of the other answers that state that looking at many, many projects for mini-examples of what you want to do in your own app is the way to go.

However, you asked for an example of an app demonstrating best practices.

You could do worse than to read Matt Gallagher's blog, [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/) from beginning to end. However, the app example you asked for is [right here.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/process-of-writing-ios-application.html)

Not only will it show a variety of techniques, some novel design and best-practices, but also he points out where he feels that he might have done something better.

It's a great read.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest the following process: (it worked for me)

1. Think of an advanced app. that you eventually want to be proficient enough to create.
2. Make a top-down problem-solving tree containing the necessary skills required to build your final app.
3. Use this tree to divide your final app. into 'sub apps'. Start at the bottom of the tree, find a tutorial specifically for that skill, and make a "Hello World" app. that uses that skill.
4. Keep progressing upwards, creating 'sub apps' as you go.
5. When you are finally ready to make your final app. (it will take a while), you will have a good handle on how iOS development works. It will also be a great test of your knowledge via direct application!

Getting the hang of iOS development can be tricky; it really does require a top-down approach, and every online resource I've found takes a linear one. The only way that I think a linear approach to learning iOS development would be manageable, is to take it one small task at a time.

As for specific resources, I always google "[what I want to do] iPhone SDK" and browse the tutorials and forum posts that come up.

Here are some open source iOS apps. However, they aren't very well documented and are also very advanced.

- [TKAWebView](http://code.google.com/p/tkawebview/) - A subclass of UIWebView that handles authentication and downloading.
- [Welcome to your Mac](http://code.google.com/p/welcometoyourmac/) - An iOS app. to VNC into a PC/Mac and do some cool stuff.
- [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) - A settings screen creator for your apps.

Good luck!

Comment: I personally do the exact same thing as in your 5 points. Even if you know a little more is extremely handy.

Answer (score 9):

The people behind the Parse platform have made two complete projects.

For each project there is the complete source code, a tutorial and the resulting app is also available from the AppStore.

- Anywall: https://parse.com/anywall
- Anypic: https://parse.com/anypic

They both rely heavily on the Parse platform as the data source, but you still get a feel for an iOS project.

Answer (score 3):

[Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) is a great open-source app that uses 3D OpenGL to render complex models of molecules.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep coding my friend. You'll learn over a period of time. The best way to get dirty in a mud fight is to jump into it... Weird analogy but you get the point.

Maybe someday, we all will learn from you then !

Comment: Now, this is exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said there many and many source codes are available internet, but most are incomplete.

I found some Open **source codes of REAL application currently available through Apple app store** are given here

**[Free iPhone App Source Codes of real apps](http://iphone-development-source-codes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sample-post.html)**

and also, you can find many answers here on stackoverflow question - [**Are there any Open-source iPhone applications around?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around/9091285#9091285)

Answer (score 3):

You can download free IOS sample projects from http://devcodemarket.com

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread but I've also been looking for good objective-c code examples recently and I just realized that [TextEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011741)'s source code is available at the [Mac Developer Library webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types).

Also, here are some popular objective-c libraries that have caught my attention:

- [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods)
- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Answer (score 1):

you can also go through UICatalog from Developers Library and download the sample code. just google it and you will find a project containing all basics of iphone.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any perfect project that can demonstrate all the qualities of great code. Developers have stylistic preferences and may make mistakes. That said, you should look at a lot of different projects and try to look at the conventions used.

I'd suggest starting on [GitHub](http://GitHub.com). Besides for seeing code, you'll see what libraries are out there, which may help further your projects later on. Here's [the Objective-C page on GitHub](https://github.com/languages/Objective-C).

(Also, [I (GitHub link)](http://github.com/MosheBerman) think you're wrong about iOS devs not being in favor open source. Yes, there's money to be made, but you can't sell a [CSV paring library](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) on the App Store as is.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios

That is Firefox for iOS, written in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

[Cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) has a wide range of controls written using Objective-C & Swift.

I believe these days, this is one of the most famous website for iOS Developers.

*But, before you jump onto this, you have to learn* ***Objective-C & Swift*** *very well, so that you will understand how to use the controls in your app which makes your app smooth.*